# How to fix <NumericProperty name=> in list python kivy?

Tags: python, list, kivy, kivymd

I tried to make kivy display my list.
This is my simple python code for testing:

```
class test(BoxLayout):
    pass

class testApp(App):
    numberx = NumericProperty(10)
    numbery = NumericProperty(5)

    list = [numberx,numbery]

testApp().run()
```

this is my kv file:

```
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label
test:

<test>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    on_parent: for x in app.list: self.add_widget(Label(text = str(x) ))
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DamTl.png)

The output show:

```
NumericProperty name=numberx

NumericProperty name=numbery

NumericProperty name=numberx

NumericProperty name=numbery
```

But I want it to show:

```
10

5
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

First, Using the `on_parent` event results in that code being executed twice (once when `parent` is initialized to `None`, and once when `parent` is set to the `testApp` window). That is why you see 4 items instead of just 2. You can use the `on_kv_post` event to get it to happen just once.

Second, the `list` that you create contains the class attributes, `numberx` and `numbery`. But while `Properties` are defined at the class level, they are actually instance attributes, so that list contains the wrong objects. To fix that, you can define that `list` either as a `ReferenceListProperty`, or by defining it in the `testApp` instance (perhaps in an `__init__()` method) so that you are using the instance attributes.

Here is a modified version of your `testApp` class that uses the `ReferenceListProperty`:

```
class testApp(App):
    numberx = NumericProperty(10)
    numbery = NumericProperty(5)
    list = ReferenceListProperty(numberx, numbery)
```

And here is a modified version of your `kv` that uses the `on_kv_post` event:

```
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label
test:

<test>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    on_kv_post:
        for x in app.list: self.add_widget(Label(text = str(x) ))
```

Comment: It help me a lot! Thank you so much Sir for your help